# Difference between "senex "and "senilis"?

Tags: word-comparison, word-choice

What would be the differences in uses of "senilis" and "senex".

I know "senilis" is constructed with senex+illis, it should help me, but I don't get it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! And good question!

Comment: Thank you for your good & interesting answer! This site seems more userfriendly than the other Stackexchanges! Good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As adjectives, the main distinction is that **senex** is said of a person, while **senilis** is said of things belonging or relative to such a person.

   A simple example could be ***senex*** vir **seniles** cogitationes cogitat, an old man has senile thoughts/the thoughts of an old man/thoughts typical of their age.

   The best *attested* example I can find is:

   > *Quae bello est habilis, Veneri quoque convenit aetas.
   >
   >   Turpe **senex** miles, turpe **senilis** amor* ([Ovid, Amores 1.9](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0068:text=Am.:book=1:poem=9&highlight=senex%2Csenilis))

   The author contrasts the ability for love and war in both young and old people. A literal translation of the second verse could be: *[An] old soldier [is a] shameful [thing], old people's love [is also a] shameful [thing]*. The soldier is *old*, but his love is *senile*. Anyway translation of poetry is  better in the hands of (native) poets, so:

   > Tis shame for eld in waive or love to be (Marlowe, c. 1580)
   >
   > The old in both unserviceable prove,
   >   Infirm in war, and impotent in love. (Cromwell, 1855)
2. Other differences include **senex** being tens of times more frequent in the literature, and allowing its usage as a noun.
3. A possible source of confusion is the fact that both **senilis** in Latin and *senile* in English (as happens in other languages too), can be used figuratively as a synonym of **senex**/*old*.

I hope it helps.